# CSS auto overflow in mobile browser glitch

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Wow, one thing after another! Okay. So I've been following an example in making a working chatbox- and it works properly (in terms of browser-server interaction, minus some obvious security things I probably should be implementing).

HOWEVER, I am trying to change the styling of my chatbox so that I can scroll in any browser, including mobile ones. Really, the problem is NOT being capable of scrolling in and of itself- overflow:auto property in CSS does work in every browser, save for just one small detail.

If you test this with a mobile browser, you'll find that you can scroll all the way to the bottom... but just when you get to the end, the textbox seems to snap a little bit of a ways back up instead of staying at the end. NOT ALL THE WAY TO THE TOP, but like 3 pixels or so. I really don't know what to do. I've researched a thing called a "rubber band" effect in mobile browsers, but I'm not quite sure that's related to my problem. Is it? Or is it possibly more related to the divs I'm posting inside the chatbox from the back end?

chatroom.php

```
<?php session_start();
#session_regenerate_id(true);
include ("dbconfig.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION['introd']))
{   
    header("Location: intro.php");
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{   
    header("Location: index.php");
}
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <title>My Webpage</title>
<!--    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>-->
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "site.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="index.html?img=favicon" type="image/ico" />
    <script>




        </script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php include("header.php"); ?>

                <div id="wrapper">
                    <div id="menu">
                        <p class="welcome">Welcome, <b><?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?></b></p>
                        <div style="clear:both"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="chatbox"><?php
                    if(file_exists("log.html") && filesize("log.html") > 0){
                        $handle = fopen("log.html", "r");
                        $contents = fread($handle, filesize("log.html"));
                        fclose($handle);

                        echo $contents;
                    }
                    ?></div>

                    <form name="message" action="">
                        <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
                        <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
                    </form>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                // jQuery Document
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    setInterval (loadLog, 2000);    //Reload file every 2500 ms or x ms if you wish to change the second parameter

                    //If user submits the form
                    $("#submitmsg").click(function(event){

                        var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
                        $.post("post.php", {text:clientmsg});
                        //alert("About to post");
                        //event.preventDefault();
                        /*$.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "post.php",
                            data: {text:clientmsg},
                            //dataType: text,
                            error: function(){
                                alert("Error receiving text");
                            },
                            success: function(response){
                                alert("Submission received: " + response);
                            },
                        });*/
                        $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
                        return false;
                    });

                    //Load the file containing the chat log
                    function loadLog(){     
                        var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20; //Scroll height before the request
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "log.html",
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(html){        
                                $("#chatbox").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div   

                                //Auto-scroll           
                                var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20; //Scroll height after the request
                                if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){
                                    $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal'); //Autoscroll to bottom of div
                                }               
                            },
                        });
                    }
                });
                </script>

                <center><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></center>    

            <p class = "content"> This is a page that is a scrap work in progress. </p>


            <?php include("footer.php"); ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

site.css

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: green;
    }

    p {
        font-family:"sans-serif";
        font-size:1.875em;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-style: bold;
    }

    p.welcome {
        font-family:"verdana";
        font-size:1.875em;
        color: white:
        text-align: center;
        font-style:bold;
    }

    p.content {
        font-family:"verdana";
        font-size:1em;
        color: white;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    p.nostyling {
        color:black;
    }

    div.contentContainer {
        border: 1;
        cellspacing: 5;
        cellpadding: 15;
        width: 50%;
        bgcolor: 251111;
    }

    img{
        display:block;
        margin:auto;
    }

    div.main {
        width:50%;
        margin:auto;
        background:#251111;
    }

    div.bridge {
        width:100%
    }

    div.deck {
        width:100%
    }

    div.control {
        float:left;
        margin:0;
        padding:1em;
        color:white;
    }

    div.arsenal {
        margin-left:25%;
        background-color:#0A1616;
        padding: 1em;
        border: 15px solid #251111;
    }

    body {
        background-color: #393635;
        color: blue;
    }

    #wrapper, #loginform {
    margin:0 auto 0 -7;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    width:450px;
    border:2px solid #ACD8F0; }

#loginform { padding-top:18px; }

    #loginform p { margin: 5px; }

#chatbox {
    text-align:left;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#fff;
    height:270px;
    width:430px;
    border:1px solid #ACD8F0;
    overflow:auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}

#usermsg {
    width:395px;
    border:1px solid #ACD8F0; }

#submit { width: 60px; }

.error { color: #ff0000; }

#menu { padding:12.5px 25px 12.5px 25px; }


.msgln { margin:0 0 2px 0; }
```

post.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    $text = $_POST['text'];

    $fp = fopen("log.html", 'a') or die("Unable to open/write file!");
    #chmod("log.html", 0777);
    fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'>(".date("g:i A").") <b>".$_SESSION['user']."</b>: ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div>");
    fclose($fp);
    echo "Just wrote the file";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
position: relative;
```

to the chatbox

Comment: That's a good try, but that doesn't appear to work either... also completely makes my layout worse overall on that page for my mobile browsers, and I'm sure I could've laid it out better to begin with, but that's besides the point...

Comment: It looks much better on my phone too. And stays great on the desktop!... I can see how relative addresses that, but why do you think it might have skipped up when I tried to scroll to the bottom? I'm just curious to know.

Comment: To be honest I'm still learning this stuff. I've just found that playing with the  position types sometimes help when getting something to stay how you want it.